# How can I determine if a process has a window, and subsequently show, hide or close it?

Tags: command-line, scripts, window-manager, window, process

Is it possible, either through a shell script or terminal command, assuming you have the PID, determine if it has a main window (form), and then get info about it (title) and show/hide/close it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I minimize a window from the command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4876/can-i-minimize-a-window-from-the-command-line)

Comment: This question is *not* an exact dupe, since it includes tracing down (possibly multiple) windows of an application with given `pid`, then perform an arbitrary action on it.  The linked question only asks for on element of that.

Comment: Dupe question asks about choosing any already open window. The answers there ( not necessarily the accepted one ) provide sufficient info. But that's my opinion :)

Comment: @Serg the *question* defines the dupe, not possible answers. Apart from that, I don't see *this* question answered there.

Comment: I never said answers define the dupe, I only said they provide sufficient info for what OP wants to achieve. The possible dupe question asks  "Is it possible to minimize a window from terminal ? " This one asks "is it possible to show/hide/close it? " So aside from just asking for extra operations (which can be achieved with the same set of commands  ), technically they are duplicates.

Comment: @Serg We might have to remove the comments, but *just asking for extra operations* defines half the question, if not more, so how can this be a dupe? Thousands of questions here have an overlap (probably bigger then this one), without being a dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Script to look up possible window(s) of given pid, then show, minimize or close it

Since you mention the command line, the script below runs in a terminal window. You run it with the `pid` as an argument, e.g.:

```
python3 /path/to/script.py 1234
```

Subsequently, a window (list) appears, of which you can choose a (list-) number and type an option to perform on it:

```
Current Windows for pid 2189:
------------------------------------------------------------
[1] Niet-opgeslagen document 1 - gedit
[2] testbackup.py (~/Bureaublad) - gedit

------------------------------------------------------------
Type window number + option:
-k  [kill (gracfully)]
-m  [minimize]
-s  [show]
Press <Enter> to cancel
------------------------------------------------------------
1 -k
```

If there are no windows:

```
There are no windows for pid 1234
```

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys

pid = sys.argv[1]

message = """
------------------------------------------------------------
Type window number + option:
-k  [kill (gracfully)]
-m  [minimize]
-s  s[how]
<Enter> to cancel
------------------------------------------------------------
"""
# just a helper function
get = lambda cmd: subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()
# get the window list
wlist = [l.split()[0] for l in get(["wmctrl", "-lp"]).splitlines() if pid in l]
# create a indexed list of window name, id
wdata = [[i+1, get(["xdotool", "getwindowname", w_id]), w_id] \
         for i, w_id in enumerate(wlist)]

# if the list is not empty (windows exist)
if wdata:
    # print the window list
    print("\nCurrent Windows for pid "+pid+":\n"+"-"*60)
    for item in wdata:
        print("["+str(item[0])+"]", item[1])
    # ask for user input (see "message" at the top)
    action = input(message)
    action = action.split()
    # run the chosen action
    try:
        subj = [item[2] for item in wdata if item[0] == int(action[0])][0]
        options = ["-k", "-m", "-s"]; option = options.index(action[1])
        command = [
            ["wmctrl", "-ic", subj],
            ["xdotool", "windowminimize", subj],
            ["wmctrl", "-ia", subj],
            ][option]
        subprocess.Popen(command)    
    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        pass
else:
    print("There are no windows for pid", pid)
```

#### How to use

1. The script uses both `xdotool` and `wmctrl`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wmctrl xdotool
   ```
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `get_wlist.py`
3. Run it with the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/get_wlist.py <pid>
   ```

#### Explanation on the procedure

---

*About [xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/xdotool.1.html) and [wmctrl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/wmctrl.1.html):*

To manipulate, move or close windows, there are two important tools on Linux: `xdotool` and `wmctrl`. Of these two, `xdotool` is probably the most robust one, which I prefer in general. Although the options of both tools overlap, they do complete each other however, and to create a window *list* we simply need `wmctrl`.

In most cases therefore, I end up using a mixture of both tools.

---

*What the script does:*

- The script gets the currently opened window list, using the command:

  ```
  wmctrl -lp
  ```

  Which gives us information on both the window id and the pid it belongs to, with an output, looking like:

  ```
  0x05a03ecc  0 2189   jacob-System-Product-Name Niet-opgeslagen document 1 - gedit
  ```
- The script then filters out the windows, belonging to the corresponding pid, looks up the window name with the `xdotool` command:

  ```
  xdotool getwindowname <window_id>
  ```

  and displays the found windows *by name*. Under the hood, these windows are *numbered*.
- subsequently, if the user types a number + an option, the corresponding action is performed on the chosen window:

  ```
  wmctrl -ic <window_id>
  ```

  to close the window gracefully, or

  ```
  xdotool windowminimize <window_id>
  ```

  to minimize the chosen window, or

  ```
  wmctrl -ia <window_id>
  ```

  to raise the window.