# What command can I use to minimize the current terminal window?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, window-control

Which command can I use to minimize the current terminal window. i.e. this should do the same as a click on the minimize window control:

[image]

Comment: Possible repost of this topic: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4876/can-i-minimize-a-window-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 0):

### About xdotool

> xdotool lets you programatically (or manually) simulate keyboard input
>          and mouse activity, move and resize windows, etc. It does this using
>          X11's XTEST extension and other Xlib functions.

### How to minimize active terminal window using xdotool

You can minimize the current active terminal window like that

```
xdotool windowminimize $(xdotool getactivewindow)
```

**Be aware:** This is not specific to gnome-terminal

Answer (score 0):

A few terminal emulators (not including gnome-terminal) support the escape sequence `ESC [ 2 t` to minimize the window:

```
echo -ne '\e[2t'
```