# Toggle terminal between minimized and restore with hotkey

Tags: shortcut-keys, 18.04, gnome-terminal, window-management

I'm recently coming from Windows, and I loved [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsQuake.html) - specifically the feature that I could switch between minimized / restored with a simple hotkey.

I'm using [Tilix](https://gnunn1.github.io/tilix-web/) on 18.04, and I like Tilix, but the only way I can find to accomplish the same thing with Tilix is by using Quake mode - in Quake mode, the toggle between hidden / visible is accomplished the same way.  Thing is, I don't much like Quake mode.  I have two monitors, and I like to move windows to the side at my leisure.

Is there a way to toggle window between visible (not full screen) and minimized / hidden - without resorting to quake mode?

Comment: I do not see an immediate solution without scripting. Dash to Dock or Dash to Panel might provide you the behaviour that you want, however for all applications on the dash. These extensions feature "Appkeys", i.e. you can summon the first app on the laucher with Win+1, the second with Win+2 etc. If in the options you set "Behavirour" tp "Minimize, then the hotkey will toggle between showing and minimizing the app.

Comment: @vanadium I know what you are talking about.  I'll investigate further.  Thanks.

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/4892/349837) commands to minimize/maximize might help you.

Answer (score 1):

There are 5 steps for this:

1. Go to Settings > Devices > Keyboard Shortcuts
2. Create Custom Shortcuts

   Name: Tilix 
   Command: tilix --quake 
   Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> (Anything you prefer)
3. sudo nano .zshrc
4. Add following instructions there

   ```
    prompt_context() {
      if [[ "$USER" != "$DEFAULT_USER" || -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ]]; then

      fi
    }
    AGNOSTER_PROMPT_SEGMENTS+="prompt_end"
   ```
5. Save and restart terminal